# What's the difference between "reach out to", "drop in on", and "call on"?

Tags: synonyms

What is the difference between "reach out to", "drop in on", and "call on" in terms of meaning? Do they mean the same?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you Googled those expressions?

Comment: Actually, I got a little bemused!

Comment: If you 'drop in on' a friend, you make an unexpected social visit to their home. _One_ meaning of 'call on someone' is to visit them. 'Reach out to someone' has the sense of making a special effort to get in touch with them because you feel they are in need of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reach out to" can imply contacting someone who is not exactly close to you, you would use it for a professional acquaintance or someone in a professional context.

"Drop in on" implies calling or visiting someone in a casual context.

"Call on" is more formal, and it's not very commonly used for individual people. It could be used in the context of publicly asking organizations, institutions, societies or groups to do something.